# Adding int value to database giving error, yet string value works

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-express

I am currently developing in an MVC project, using Entity framework, and SQL Express server.

I am trying to add a user to a Users table. The user is currently compromised of the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [UserID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Admin]  BIT NOT NULL,
);
```

When I go through the function below to add into the above table:

```
[HttpPost]
public String AddUser(List<String> values)
{
    using (DataBASE db = new DataBASE())
    {
        Users newUser = new Users();
        newUser.UserID = Int32.Parse(values[0]); //There is correct data stored here as an int value
        newUser.Admin = Boolean.Parse(values[1]); //There is correct data stored here as an bool value
        db.Users.Add(newUser); //The newUser object is correct
        db.SaveChanges(); //The error occurs here
    }
    return "success";
}
```

EDIT, this is the Users class requested (which is changed to a string whenever stored into the database):

```
[Table("Users")]
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set;}
    public bool Admin { get; set; }
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
"Cannot insert the value NULL into column UserID, table ‘…\\DATABASE.MDF.dbo.Users';
 column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

The value is not NULL and the database is connecting correctly (as the delete function works properly and I when I break into the function the database connection is correct and the function is giving the correct data before updating by adding a new user.

When I change the database to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [UserID] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Admin]  BIT NOT NULL,
);
```

And I add a user using the following function (changed the function above to where it doesn't pass an int but rather keeps the string value):

```
[HttpPost]
public String AddUser(List<String> values)
{
    using (DataBASE db = new DataBASE())
    {
        Users newUser = new Users();
        newUser.UserID = values[0]; //There is correct data stored here as an string value
        newUser.Admin = Boolean.Parse(values[1]); //There is correct data stored here as an bool value
        db.Users.Add(newUser); //The newUser object is correct
        db.SaveChanges(); //NO error occurs here
    }
    return "success";
}
```

This is the Users class changed to a string to work for the string solution:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public string UserID { get; set;}
    public bool Admin { get; set; }
}
```

Is there something against using an INT value in the database that I do not know of?

Comment: In your c# code, what data type is your `newUser.UserID`?

Comment: show your `Users` class. And unrelated but please name your class in singular. Most probably your Id has Identity flag set.

Comment: @Baraa try to insert directly, you may find answer

Comment: @JohnBustos & Mathew I have added the user class and its current types which is currently an int.

Comment: @ARUN inserting through the database manually? Or writing out the SQL Statement my self instead of using the Add function? I insterted manually which works fine no matter what the variables are. But may write out my own SQL statement

Comment: One more question, is your `UserId` field in the DB an auto-incrementing identity field, perhaps? If so, your problem may be that the number assigned isn't matching what the DB expects.

Comment: @JohnBustos It is not auto-incrementing, just a unique value!

Comment: @JohnBustos & others, So it is as simple as having 2 solutions one with ints throughout and one with string throughout ... the int gives the error above and the string solution adds the user correctly. I want to use int though because it makes sense to. I just don't understand why it is not working?

Comment: @Baraa the only place where I see a chance is,  newUser.UserID = values[0]; you can insert only one null, var chk = values[0]; , check this first

Comment: @ARUN I promise that I have checked it and it is not NULL value, there is an actual int value being passed in to newUsers. the newUsers has the UserId and true or false for Admin. It still manages to error out. Saying that it is NULL but it is not.

Comment: @Baraa  try using convert.toInt32() , parse produces null

Comment: @ARUN I will try this...but it did not produce null as I can see the newUser objects ends up have the integer it parses out of values[0] and the bool value as well

Comment: @Baraa ok, I am out of solutions

Comment: @ARUN did the convert that way you stated above. I have multiple developers that are looking at the code as well. We are all out of solutions. I have absolutely no idea why it would produce the error it does.

Comment: @Baraa if the ID is too big may not work

Comment: @ARUN I have tried passing it in small numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add attribute

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

to your `UserId` property. It says that EF should get value from property instead of defaulting on database level.

Comment: Thank you...I thought I was loosing my mind. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Users newUser = new Users();
        newUser.UserID = Int32.Parse(values[0]); //There is correct data stored here as an int value
        newUser.Admin = Boolean.Parse(values[1]); //There is correct data stored here as an bool value


        db.Users.Attach(newUser);


        db.Users.Add(newUser); //The newUser object is correct
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Final try, I am not sure , Just came to mind

if same id already in database, may have trouble

Comment: I am sorry the above did not work, I just posted a solution to my issue but had to execute raw query. Will never know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest this isn't much of answer. But the best thing that I was able to do to solve my issue, which is writing a raw query and executing it below works with int values in the database and throughout the application. I still do not know, and probably will never know, why the above function does not work for int values.

```
        using (DataBASE db = new DataBASE())
        {
            try
            {
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users VALUES({0},{1})", Int32.Parse(values[0]), Boolean.Parse(values[1]));
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var exception = e;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Look at Kirill Bestemyanov's answer. `User`'s primary key is not an identity field (auto-incremented), but EF assumes it is, by default. Therefore, it doesn't include the field in the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try rename the UserID column to Id or UsersId, removing the [Key] notation, following the EF convention, but just for test.